# Please Convert media-centre to media-center on Server Fault

Tags: support, retag-request

The tag media-centre on ServerFault is spelled incorrectly, it should be changed to media-center.

**Edit**

When I made this post I did not realize that "center" was spelled "centre" outside of the US. The powers that be need to decide if a retag is warranted. Additionally, a determination should be rendered if US spellings are what should be used for tagging.

That said, maybe I am a dumb/ugly American but I find spelling "center," "centre" jarring. Further the Google Chrome spell checker marks "centre" as incorrect. To some extent these posts probably apply: [The Ugly American Programmer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001248.html) and [Forced To Write English Syntax Code – Simplicity or Burden](http://www.codesqueeze.com/forced-to-write-english-syntax-code-simplicity-or-burden/).

Probably the best summary of where this thread is headed is contained within this [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/) comic:

[image]

Comment: downvoted because the spelling is in fact correct

Comment: Upvoted because it is stupid to have both british and american spellings for tags.

Comment: To represent the non-native English speakers: who cares? Your little quarrels about *ou* or *o*, *er* or *re* are amusing in the beginning, but become boring fast.

Comment: I _am_ a native English speaker, and I agree with John. Try to find a more useful outlet for your time and energy.

Comment: It should be spelled right, 'center'.

Comment: while we have the chance... Change it all 'center' or 'centre' to "centr" and 'colour' or 'color' to "colr" ends the debate forever

Comment: @Shahmir: initialiing? Thats fun!  :)

Comment: u know what in the early days of coding... I had a whole 4 hours of nightmare in figuring out why 'background-colour:#000000' wasn't working. Im for the movement.

Comment: Just to let you know John my First up vote on Meta belongs to you.. :D

Answer (score 6):

Just because they are both accurate spellings (depending on your locale) it makes no sense at all to keep both as tags. Combine them into media-center (the american spelling) and strive to keep that as the default.

Comment: Maybe you should care more about the hyphen, than about the ending.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: mediacenter, media-center - both are used-

Comment: I would imagine that mediacenter should also be merged into the media-center tag as well.

Answer (score 2):

'centre' is the non-US spelling.  See here:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/centre

Comment: It's also the "fat-fingered US" spelling...

Comment: That's the spelling for "center". But there is simply no such thing as MS Media Centre. MS is not marketing that stuff with that spelling and I don't think they ever will.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a large clue in "English"? As in England?

British-English would be more consistent to help all the H1B Indians doing a damn fine job (just cheaper) in the USA. Or off-shore. Or our European neighbours, Or the Commonwealth based users...

There are far more pressing issues such as sqlserver vs sql-server tags, and is it sequel or S-Q-L?

Answer (score 1):

It aint spelt wrong till there isnt a red line under it.

Its my answer because thats the way i work these days :D

Comment: So many apostrophes left on the floor...

Comment: they wrnt sqigly undrlind red :D